# User input only works for the last file extension in a folder

Tags: python, user-input, file-extension, os.path

I am struggling to fix a bug in my code. The variable (fext) is only true for the last file in a folder. So if by chance the last file is 'jpg' then my code will continue as planned. But if by chance the last file is a 'gpx' or a 'csv' then the Else error will activate even though there is a 'jpg' file in the folder.

Can somebody please help me refine my code so that this work if all file types are in the folder? I am still quite new to Python and stuck on how to proceed.

Here is my code below:

```
import os, string
from os.path import isfile, join

file_path = input("Enter the folder link: ")
print("")
TF = False

path_it = (os.path.join(root, filename)
    for root, _, filenames in os.walk(file_path)
    for filename in filenames)
for path in path_it:
    fext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[1]
    fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]

while True:
    file_type = input("Enter file extention (e.g. txt, wav, jpg, gpx, pdf): ")
    print(file_type)
    if file_type in fext:
        TF = True
        break
    else:
        print("\n*** There is no '" + file_type + "' file extension in this folder, please try again.\n") 

Other code...
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you check your code : it is not properly formatted (for loop for os.walk) and path_it use filename which is defined after…

Comment: Your for loop is overwriting the fext and fname variable on every iteration, thus only the last extension type will match. Try a list comprehension

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The formatting has been corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension is likely your best solution to get your desired result. This will store all the filetypes in the directory passed in a list.

```
fext = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[1] for path in path_it]
fname = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[1] for path in path_it]
```

But, you also need to make sure that the input file type matches the format. The above will give you (for example) `['.csv', '.pdf', '.gpx']`, so you need to make sure that the format of the input is the same, in other words, not just `'csv'` but `'.csv'` otherwise there will be no match.

The while loop can also be changed to `while not TF`, and once TF changes to `True`, the loop will be broken, instead of breaking the loop using `break.`

Answer (score 0):

The fext and fname variables should return an iterable if you are to check against all extensions contained within the folder. Try the following list comprehensions.

```
fext = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[1] for path in path_it]
fname = [os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[1] for path in path_it]
```